# How to enable auto-moving caret to word when clicking in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, caret

It`s difficult to explain, better see images below.

When clicking within any part of empty line, cursor stays where I clicked:

[image: what should be fixed]

And how it should behave:

[image: how it should work]

Small notice, before updating it behaved normally, but after it changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what you have got here: `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General`. Make sure that `Allow caret placement | After the end of line` option is disabled.

[image]